# Failed to set unsafe attribute upload yii

Tags: yii

uploading images has been causing much trouble. I'm always having two problems. First it always fail to upload or unable to find the files when using asset manager when it is there in the folder!! So when my controller says unlink the file, it won't unlink anything. Second, it'll show failed to set unsafe attribute when my rules are set to safe.

Here is my rule:

```
array('product_image,product_gallery_1, product_gallery_2, product_gallery_3, product_gallery_4, product_gallery_5, product_gallery_6', 'file','types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png','allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update', 'safe'=>true),
```

on view I do have

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
```

Here's a section on update controller. It does upload multiple images:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $old_img = $model->product_image;

        if(isset($_POST['Product']))
        {
            $model->update_date = time();
            $model->product_approval_status = "N";

            $t_product_image = $model->product_image;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Product'];

            $product_image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'product_image');

            $storeid = $model->store_id;
            $date = date('mdy');
            $rnd = rand(0,9999);

            $f_product_image = "{$rnd}-{$date}{$storeid}-{$product_image}";  

            //main img
            if(!empty($product_image))
            {
                $model->product_image = $f_product_image;
            }
            else
            {
                if(file_exists(Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/shop/thumbnail/thumb_'.$model->product_image))
                    unlink(Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/shop/thumbnail/thumb_'.$old_img);
                if(file_exists(Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/shop/product/'.$model->product_image)&& ($old_img !==null))
                    unlink(Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/shop/thumbnail/'.$old_img);

                $model->product_image = $t_product_image;
            }

            if($model->save())
            {
                $url = Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/shop/product/';
                $thumb = Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/shop/thumbnail/';
                if(!empty($product_image))
                {
                    $product_image->saveAs($url.$f_product_image);
                    $this->createThumb($url.$f_product_image, $thumb.'thumb_' . $f_product_image);
                }

                $this->redirect(array('submitted'));
            }
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: that's the error: Failed to set unsafe attribute (product_image)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your current defined [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/)

In your model, you specify the attributes safe under the update scenario.

```
array('product_image, ..., product_gallery_6',  ...  'on'=>'update', 'safe'=>true)
```

Therefore, in your controller, you need to set the scenario.

```
$model = new MyActiveRecord('update');
```

Since you are using a function you may not have control over, you can explicitly set this:

```
$model->scenario = 'update';
```

Note that your problem might be elsewhere, depending on the operation of loadModule(), because ceratin ActiveRecord scenarios are automatically loaded. See the section 'CActiveRecord scenarios' in the linked page.